# call function from dll to exe c++

Tags: c++, dll

I have a test dll. After event in dll I want use callback function from dll to exe.

test.dll
.h

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall getSum(int , int );

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall callSum(int , int );
```

.cpp

```
int  callSum(int a, int b)
{
    return getSum(a, b);
}
```

myexe
.cpp

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall getSum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}


typedef int(__stdcall * callSumFn)(int a, int b);
```

and load

```
  hLib=LoadLibrary(L"test.dll");
    if(hLib==NULL)
    {
       ...
       return -1;
    }


   callSumFn callSum = (callSumFn)GetProcAddress(hLib, L"_callSum@8");
    if (!callSum)
    {
        //cerr << "Failed to get function address" << endl;
        FreeLibrary(hLib);
        return 1;
    }

    callSum(3, 4);
```

Error:

> Error 18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_getSum
>   referenced in function callSum    test.obj    test

with compile test.dll

whats wrong? Maybe there is a better way? 
Thank you.

Comment: The .h file is broken, it declares getSum() as `__declspec(dllexport)`.  Which is only true when you build the DLL, it cannot be true when you build the test.  Then it is `dllimport`.  Using a macro to choose between the two is boilerplate.

Comment: After you linked myexe.exe, you should have gotten a "myexe.lib" file as well.
Add this to you linker command of test.dll.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency: the exe depends on `callsum()` from the dll and the dll depends on `getsum()` from the dll.

If you want a callback you need to define a function pointer and pass a function from the exe as a parameter to the dll function.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the variable function `getSum` in your DLL, but you haven't declared it. Declaring `getSum` in test.dll should rid you of the error.